# iOS communication with backend using APNs

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, swift2

How do I send push notifications to my iOS app? I need to send small messages even when the application is in the background or not running.Is there a simple tutorial. I searched a lot and only found third party solutions. Is there a direct way to access APNs, and if not which third party should I go for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send remote notifications, you need your own server that is authorized (you can grab a remote notification certificate from your developer account  from developer.apple.com). Then you just follow Apple's API to send a notification to a specific device.

I followed a [Ray Wenderlich guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) a while back and found it useful.

However, you might not want to set up your own server and stuff. This is where third-party solutions come in. I've worked with [Parse](http://www.parse.com)'s push notification system and found that it is pretty easy to set up.

Comment: Any idea about PushKit. Is VoIP more reliable?

Comment: They are the same in terms of reliableness. VoIP provides more flexibility but for me I didn't need it, so I went with standard.

Comment: I've followed the instruction given on the Ray Wenderlich guide and got it to work, but when I archive the app using Ad Hoc it does not work. What should be the code signing under Build Settings?

Comment: Make sure the certificate you generated from apple is for release instead of development or testing. I ran into this issue once.

Comment: I've done that. I think I'm messing up the code signing part. What should the values be there?